# Преобразование шестнадцатеричного представления числа в целочисленный знаковый тип

Tags: c, массивы

Есть текст в массиве `unsigned char`, который надо последовательно просматривать, это я успешно делал, пока не попалось число в шестнадцатеричной с. с. Как на Си преобразовать число в текстовом виде в шестнадцатеричной с. с. в число `int` простыми средствами, подобно `scanf`?

Comment: Так вот прямо scanf и воспользоваться. Формат как и при печати шестнадцетиричных %x или %X

Comment: Mike, я читал про scanf, в литературе говориться, что она считывает данные из stdin (клавиатуры), а мне надо обрабатывать данные из массива.

Comment: `strtol` вестимо.

Comment: @0Zerro Надо воспользоваться версией, работающей со строкой, а не стандартным вводом. `sscanf()`

Comment: что может быть проще? `char str[] = "0x1800785";
int num;
sscanf(str, "%x", &num);
printf("0x%x %i\n", num, num); `

Comment: Кстати, формат `"%i"` с равным успехом считывает как десятичные, так и шестнадцатиричные (если они начинаются с префикса `0x`) числа

Comment: Спасибо, Mike и avp за полезную информацию!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/MEMTOy

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void)
{
  const char *s = "20";
 
  int n;
  sscanf(s, "%x", &n);
  printf("%d", n);
 
  return 0;
}
```

```
32
```

Comment: Qwertiy, спасибо!

Comment: @0Zerro, а ответ принять?)

Comment: простите, забыл. )